# Prometheus gauge doesn't update after some time

Tags: node.js, prometheus

I am using prom-client under nodejs, and i am writing metrics to the /metrics endpoint for prometheus to scrape them.
I can see other metrics i'm collecting updating, i.e the default metrics.

I've added a simple metric that monitors some value that fluctualtes, and all i do is send labels ( a unique identifier, and 3 more labels that stay the same for the same value ), and the  value of the gauge i am setting.

```
setPromValue(options) {
    const { val, name, uniqueID, source, target } = options;
    metrics.get(metricsNames.my_metric_name).set({
        value: val,
        labelValues: {
            name,
            uniqueID,
            source,
            target
        }
    });
}
```

I have two sets of data following one another -
"firstName", uniqueID#1, A, B, and changing values,
and a second set :
"secondName", uniqueID#2, A, B, and changing values.

Prom graph in Graphana shows only the first set of data fully came through, also the /metrics endpoint shows that the *second set* that i write following the first set that has finished, is not registering.

Thanks in advance for your help.